# SpriteKit - Frame drops on iPhone X

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iphone-x

I finally got my hands on a iPhone X to test my game, and I realized there is an odd bug. Once I launch the game the character starts shaking and the frame rate drops to 40, instead of the 60 I have on all other devices.
The shaking is also a bug I only found on the iPhone X and on no other device. But when I pause the game and return it with the following function:

```
    @objc func pauseGame()
{
    pauseButton?.isHidden = true
    pauseMenu?.isHidden = false
    gameScene?.isPaused = true      // This is the main scene, which is supposed to be paused
}
```

Or even if I just put the app in the background and return to the game, the game works just fine with no problems at all.

So, the game has problems right after launch, but those disappear once the scene is paused and returned on. 
I already checked all my setup and update functions, but none of them seem to the cause of the problem.

**EDIT:**
The problem has to be somewhere between the launch of the app and the creation of the scene in the viewcontroller, as the framerate also drops when loading an empty scene.

Comment: in your didMove to view func in your scene try adding a self.isPaused = false and see if that changes anything

Comment: @RonMyschuk I have added the line and the error still occures. However it fixes itself after a few seconds and sometimes the bug does not exist at all.

Comment: did these results change after adding that line or was it always like that?

Comment: @RonMyschuk It kind of was like that, sometimes it fixed itself after some minutes, but not after seconds.

Comment: Run the app/game, and when it falters to 40fps, pull down a notification tray or swipe up to reveal your open apps, and then go back to your app. If this returns your app to 60fps, let me know, and I'll explain what's going on.

Comment: @Confused I didn't try it the way you said, because the lags actually got better somehow. I am pretty sure though, that what you said would have stopped the lags.